# Replacing content of column 'x' from file A with column 'x' in a very large file B

Tags: python, csv

I have two files. "A" which is not too large (2GB) and "B" which is rather large at 60GB. I have a primitive code as follows:

```
import csv #imports module csv

filea = "A.csv"
fileb = "B.csv"
output = "Python_modified.csv"

source1 = csv.reader(open(filea,"r"),delimiter='\t')
source2 = csv.reader(open(fileb,"r"),delimiter='\t')
#open csv readers

source2_dict = {}

# prepare changes from file B
for row in source2:
    source2_dict[row[2]] = row[2]

# write new changed rows
with open(output, "w") as fout:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for row in source1:
        # needs to check whether there are any changes prepared
        if row[3] in source2_dict:
            # change the item
            row[3] = source2_dict[row[3]]
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Which should read through column 3 from both files and replace column 4 in file A with the contents of column 4 in file B if there's a match. However since it's reading in the large files its very slow. Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: You've loaded the smaller file into memory for lookup - make sure that's not getting swapped out and is staying in RAM (eg: it's not causing some sort of thrashing)... apart from that - you have to read each file once... if the read/write of the larger file is too slow - get faster disks is probably the only real solution...

Comment: Are the Number of Rows equal in both Files?

Comment: @stovfl no, the files are different. The larger one is a reference (B), which has column 4 that I want included as column 4 in the new file using file A's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reading `file_a` in large blocks into memory, and then process each block. This would mean you are doing a groups of reads followed by a group of writes which should help to reduce disk thrashing. You will need to decide which `block_size` to use, obviously something that will fit comfortably in memory.

```
from itertools import islice
import csv #imports module csv

file_a = "A.csv"
file_b = "B.csv"
output = "Python_modified.csv"
block_size = 10000      

# prepare changes from file B
source2_dict = {}

with open(file_b, 'rb') as f_source2:
    for row in csv.reader(f_source2, delimiter='\t'):
        source2_dict[row[3]] = row[4]       # just store the replacement value

# write new changed rows
with open(file_a, 'rb') as f_source1, open(output, "wb") as f_output:
    csv_source1 = csv.reader(f_source1, delimiter='\t')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')

    # read input file_a in large groups
    for block in iter(lambda: list(islice(csv_source1, block_size)), []):
        for row in block:
            try:
                row[4] = source2_dict[row[3]]
            except KeyError as e:
                pass

            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Secondly, to reduce memory usage, if you are just replacing one value, then just store that one value in your dictionary.

Tested using Python 2.x. If you are using Python 3.x, you will need to change your file open's, e.g.

```
with open(file_b, 'r', newline='') as f_source2:
```